# Change div html based on click from SharePoint REST API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

This works for pulling the data from the SharePoint list, question is: How do I pass down this.className, of the button clicked (or some way of getting item 2 in the list with the next button). I need to pull data from data.d.results[1] for second button and so on. Right now I just get error because classOfButton is not defined (because this.className is not passed down in success: onQuerySucceeded().

At top of the page I have two buttons:

```
<div id="buttonMaster">
<a class="product01">Product 1</a>
<a class="product02">Product 2</a>
</div>
```

I am pulling info from a SharePoint 2013 list with API:

```
const Productbuttons = document.querySelectorAll('#buttonMaster a');
for (const ProductButton of Productbuttons) {
ProductButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
getListData(this.className);
})
}

function getListData() {
var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestProductConstruct')/items;
$ajax({
url: fullUrl,
type: "GET";
headers: {
   "accept": "Appplication/json;odata=verbose",
   "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
succes: onQuerySucceeded,
error: onQueryFailed
}
});

function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
 var classOfButton = this.className;
 switch(true) {
 case classOfButton.contains('Product01');
 const product1 = data.d.results[0];
 $('step1Info').html(product1.Phase);
 $('step2Info').html(product1.Step);
 break;
 case classOfButton.contains('Product02');
 const product2 = data.d.results[1];
 $('step1Info').html(product2.Phase);
 $('step2Info').html(product2.Step);
 break;
 }
}

function onQueryFailed() {
alert('Error');
}
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: In listener, use `ev.target.className` instead of `this`.
And pay attention to case sensitivity ---> Product01 vs. product01

Comment: Thanks, updated event listener to ev.target.className and lower cased Product. Still gives me  classOfButton undefined. The className still isnt being passed down to success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found an answer with trial and error. This is a mix of things I found and changed over a day so not pretty, I will update when I get to it.

```
const Productbuttons = document.querySelectorAll('#buttonMaster a');
for (const ProductButton of Productbuttons) {
ProductButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
var buttonClass = Productbutton.getAttribute('class');
getListData(buttonClass);
})
}

function getListData(buttonClass) {
var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestProductConstruct')/items;
  $ajax({
  url: fullUrl,
  type: "GET";
  headers: {
   "accept": "Appplication/json;odata=verbose",
   "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",

  success: function(data) {
  switch(true) {
  case buttonClass === "product01":
  var xid = data.d.results[0];
  $(".step1Info").html(xid.Phase);
  $(".step2Info").html(xid.Step);
  break;
  case buttonClass === "product02":
  var xid = data.d.results[1];
  $(".step1Info").html(xid.Phase);
  $(".step2Info").html(xid.Step);
  break;
   }
  },

  error: onQueryFailed
  }
 },

function onQueryFailed() {
console.log('Error');
}
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is som issue with your code:

- First of all, use data-attributes for functionality, and keep classes for styles. If somebody delete or rename your class, your code got broken. By the way you can pass some useful data through this
- So the `switch/case` going unnecessary. You could use this data in `onQuerySucceeded()`
- I don't know how it can works your ajax call. In jQuery, you can call `$.ajax()` instead of `$ajax()`
- `fullURL` case is incorrect: `fullUrl`
- I think the fullURL is not valid eighter. You combined variables with string and function calls in not a proper way. You could use string literal instead:
  `` `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/${getByTitle('TestProductConstruct')}/items` ``
  or basic string concatenations:
  `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/' + getByTitle('TestProductConstruct') + '/items'`

Here is my final code:

```html
<div id="buttonMaster">
  <a class="product" data-product="0">Product 1</a>
  <a class="product" data-product="1">Product 2</a>
</div>
```

```js
const products = document.querySelectorAll('[data-product]')
products.forEach(product => {
  product.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    getListData(ev.target)
  })
})

const getListData = (element) => {
  const fullURL = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/${getByTitle('TestProductConstruct')}/items`

  $.ajax({
    url: fullURL,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "accept": "Appplication/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    succes: (data) => {
      onQuerySucceeded({ data, element })
    },
    error: onQueryFailed
    }
  })
}

const onQuerySucceeded = ({ data, element }) => {
  const product = data.d.results[element.dataset.product]
  $('.step-1').html(product.Phase)
  $('.step-2').html(product.Step)
}
```

Comment: This gives you getByTitle not defined and if you go back to my address that works, it does nothing without error. This may contain an item that is too new for SharePoint 2013.